# How to make clear that a parameter of a method serves as a return value?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Is there a way to show that a parameter of a method serves as return value?

If I want to return one value it is no problem:

```
public Set<Integer> addIntegerToSet(final int i) {
    Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>();
    intSet.add(i);

    return intSet;
}
```

It's easy to see that the method returns a set.

But if I want a method to return two values I need a workaround:

```
public Set<Integer> addIntegerToSet(final int i, Set<Integer> returnIntMap) {
    Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>();
    intSet.add(i);

    returnIntMap.add(i);

    return intSet;
}
```

These two pieces of code are just examples to illustrate my question and they have no practical use.

However, I want to make it obvious to the user that this set (`returnIntMap`) was manipulated as well. It is common practice to put a "final" in front of parameters that are not manipulated within a method, but this is not done consequently, not even in Java standard classes.

So, how do I show that `returnIntMap` is manipulated within the method, without just mentioning it in the java doc comments. Are there any conventions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not directly possible in Java.

Java uses pass by value. Objects and Arrays are actually pointers, so even though it looks like pass by reference, actually the reference is passed as value. This means you can modify the object, but not the reference to it.

`final` is not used that much, because it merely states that the pointer cannot be modified, but the object it points to can. Thus there is not much use to declare arguments to methods as `final` in a public interface. It is a nice safeguard in the actual implementation, though. In short: `final != const` and Java has no equivalent of `const`.

Even though you can technically only return one object, nothing stops you from returning a container that wraps several new objects into one.

If you just want to (internally) document which objects are modified you can use annotations to mark parameters as e.g. `@ReadOnly` or `@ReadWrite`. These are not part of the standard or any library I know, though there might very well exist one. Even if not, you can still define your own annotations.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to is do a pass by reference to your method arguments. That does not happen in Java. Java does a pass by value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really mark a parameter as IN or IN/OUT. You could write a more cleaner code, having your two return parameters in a new class. So you have both return parameters as the one and only return parameter:

```
public class ReturnParam {
    private final Set<Integer> intSet;
    private final Set<Integer> returnIntMap;

    public ReturnParam(final Set<Integer> intSet, final Set<Integer> returnIntMap) {
        this.intSet = intSet;
        this.returnIntMap = returnIntMap;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getIntSet() {
        return intSet;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getReturnIntMap() {
        return returnIntMap;
    }
}

// and your method could look like this
public ReturnParam addIntegerToSet(final int i) {
    Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> returnIntMap = new HashSet<>();

    intSet.add(i);
    returnIntMap.add(i);

    return new ReturnParam(intSet, returnIntMap);  // put it into the ReturnParam wrapper class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you could do this -

```
public static Set<Integer> addIntegersToSet(Set<Integer> set, final int ... arr) { 
                                                      // <-- Receive a Set and a 
                                                      //  variable number of ints.
  for (int i : arr) { // add each int to the set (possibly none to add).
    set.add(i);
  }
  return set; // return the set.
}
```

Then you could check the set size before (and after) to see how many integer(s) you added to your set.
To make your set immutable you can use `Collections.unmodifiableSet`. See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet%28java.util.Set%29). But then you can't add anything to the Set. I think you'd want to document when you changed a Set in that way.

Comment: true, but like I said: I should only serve as an example. I wanted to see the bigger picture for any datatype... like a general convention to handle several return types.

Answer (score 0):

I am speaking of a work around.
Since you are passing the set, and the method is also returning a set. So you can compare them in your calling method whether something has been changed or not.

 (you can achieve comparison by `firstSet.equals(secondSet)` or `firstSet.containsAll(secondSet)`)